# MQQueueManager C# issue

Tags: c#, websphere, ibm-mq

I have written a windows service application which is taking message from an IBM MQ Queue and processing it. The service works great on my system, but when I installed it on my dev machine it is not throwing any errors but still not doing anything.

I am logging events and got it down to the point where a call to MQQueueManager C# class is not returning a response back. I am not allowed to install the IDE on the server so I can't debug it locally on the machine.

I know this is really vague, but is there a way to figure out what is causing my code to fail? Or is it possible to debug the service remotely through my machine.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might look at running MQ trace to understand what's happening.

"strmqtrc -t all -t detail" is the command.

Answer (score 0):

here is is an artikel how to setup remote debugging: [How to: Set Up Remote Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx)
if this is not allowed, try to log anything to logfiles, i like [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/)